# como cambiar el nombre en los tooltips en chartjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip, chart.js

Tengo el siguiente grafico, usando la librería ChartJS. Tengo un inconveniente.
Actualmente tengo este resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este otro
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El punto es que como puedo cambiar el solo el nombre en el globito "**Tooltip**" y mantener otro resultado en los **labels** de abajo.

```
const etiquetas = [
            @foreach ($tot_ven as $ventas)
                '{{ $variable array }}',
            @endforeach
        ];
```

En el código anterior obtengo mi array

```
 var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: etiquetas,
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: "Reportes de Ventas",
                        data: [
                            arrays de valores
                        ],
                        backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
                        borderColor: borderColor,
                        borderWidth: 1,
                    },
                ],

            },
```

etiquetas lo pongo en el labels y me devuelve los nombres pero en reemplazo lo quiero cambiar por otro valor.

```
const puestos = [];
        for ( i = 0; i < etiquetas.length; i++) {
            puestos.push((i+1).toString()+"° Puesto");
        }

labels: puestos,
```

Tal cual como se muestra la segunda imagen, pero sale el mismo nombre. ¿Como se puede cambiar el nombre en el tooltip y ademas colocar otro valor encima de cada barra?

Gracias de antemano por su tiempo.